# Inheritance: Finding the maximum number and the most used string in a list of an inheritance class object in c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, inheritance

I have this class `Car` that inherits from `Vehicle`:

```
public class Car: Vehicle
{
    public int num;
    string name;
    public string color = "Purple";

    public Car(int num, string name)
    { 
        ...
    }
}
```

In the main class I have a list of `Vehicle`:

```
List<Vehicle> cList = new List<Vehicle>();
```

And I add different cars like that:

```
Car q = new Car(124,"BMW");
cList.Add(q);
```

Is there a way to find the minimum 'num' and the most used Car 'name' ?

Comment: This sounds like homework, so here's just a hint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347632%28v=vs.95%29.aspx for the first question and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501%28v=vs.100%29.aspx for the second.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ seems like a good choice for finding the min:

```
cList.Min(t=>t.num)
```

Would probably also go the LINQ route for getting most popular car name, but it will be slightly more complex:

```
var query = cList.GroupBy(t => t.name).OrderByDescending(t => t.Count()).First();
```

I can't test at the moment, but this should get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Given a class `Vehicle` and its subtype `Car`:

```
class Vehicle
{
  ...
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    public int    Number { get; set; }
    public string Name {  get;  set; }
}
```

And given an `IEnumerable<Vehicle>` containing a list of vehicles:

```
IEnumerable<Vehicle> vehicles = GetMeSomeVehicles() ;
```

You should be able to get the minimum value for `Car.Number` like this:

```
int minNumber = vehicles
                .Where( v => v is Car )
                .Cast<Car>()
                .Min( c => c.Number )
                ;
```

And you should be able to get the most common name along these lines:

```
string MostCommonName = vehicles
                        .OfType<Car>()
                        .GroupBy( c => c.Name , StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase )
                        .OrderByDescending( g => g.Count() )
                        .ThenBy( g => g.Key )
                        .First()
                        .Select( g => g.Key )
                        ;
```

Comment: `.Where( v => v is Car ).Cast<Car>()` can be reduced to `.OfType<Car>()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();
//Your cars...

int maxNum = carList.Max(c => c.num);
string maxOccurence = carList.Select(c => c.name).GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).First().Key;
```